# Error Invalid Login Connect DocuSign to Salesforce

Tags: docusignapi

I'm setting up the DocuSign for Salesforce for the first time for my Org. I'm the administrator for both (DocuSign and Salesforce).

***Issue - Cannot see the checkbox "Relate to Salesforce" when creating a custom tag***

I'm using the Docusign for Salesforce Administrator Guide. On page 54, it shows how to create custom tags. However, what I see when I follow steps 1-5 (figure 1 below) is different from what I was supposed to see (figure 2 below). In other words, I miss the checkbox "Relate to Salesforce". Apparently, my Salesforce account is connected to my DocuSign account, therefore I expected that this option would be available.

Figure 1 and 2 not inserted because I don't have 10 reputations yet.

I appreciate if you can guide me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If that checkbox is missing, I'd suspect that your DocuSign Connect settings are not (properly) configured for use with Salesforce.  I'd suggest you review your Connect settings (for the "**Salesforce**" Connect configuration) within DocuSign.  Information about these Connect settings can be found in this guide (starting on page 4):  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20Connect%20for%20Salesforce.pdf.